# Asp.net Web API hangs while reading from Http Client post method (SOAP Request/Response)

Tags: c#, xml, soap, async-await, dotnet-httpclient

Web API method is getting into a deadlock for larger response. Can someone point out where it is getting deadlock. The same code is invoked in a for loop.
Here is the code

```
  public async Task<string> GetXMLResponse(string baseUrl, string fullFileName, int countryId, HttpClient client, FileOperations objFileOperation, string outputfilePath)
    {

        try
        {
            var fileData = new StringBuilder(objFileOperation.ReadFile(fullFileName));
            var content = new StringContent(TransformToSOAPXml(fileData, countryId), Encoding.UTF8,
                "application/xml");
            //fileData.Clear();
            //fileData.Capacity = 0;
            SerilogMethods.LogCustomException(log, "Before sending to Tax Engine", "GetXMLResponse");
            using (HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync(baseUrl, content))
            {

                // content = null;
                response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
                if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    SerilogMethods.LogCustomException(log, "Started Recieving response from Tax Engine", "GetXMLResponse");
                    var resultContent = await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();
                    StreamReader readStream = new StreamReader(resultContent, Encoding.UTF8);
                    var postresult = await readStream.ReadToEndAsync();
                    XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(postresult);
                    doc.Save(outputfilePath);
                    readStream.Dispose();
                    resultContent.Dispose();

                    //File.WriteAllText(outputfilePath, await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());

                    SerilogMethods.LogCustomException(log, "File write Completed", "GetXMLResponse");
                   
                    return "Success";
                }

                SerilogMethods.LogCustomException(log, "Error occured in Tax Engine", "GetXMLResponse");
                //Log the SOAP response when the SOAP fails with an error message
                if (response.Content != null)
                {
                    throw new Exception(await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());
                }
                return null;
            }

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            SerilogMethods.LogError(log, ex, "GetXMLResponse");
            return null;

        }


    }
```

If I uncomment and comment the other lines, it works with File.WriteAllText

```
                    File.WriteAllText(outputfilePath, await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());
```

Can someone point out why the second solution works and not the first one.I have to even parse the xml response before saving it

Comment: You can only reader the response once with response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().  You are reading a stream object and after the first read the stream location is at the end of the stream and you cannot read again.

Comment: `StreamReader` takes ownership of the stream you pass to it, and disposes it when you dispose the reader. You shouldn’t dispose the stream yourself after that.

Comment: @sellotape So whether the above code works if I don't dispose the streamreader

Comment: @jdweng is there any solution to read and parse the response

Comment: There are lot of methods to parse xml.  The best method depends on the amoutn of data you need to parse, the size of the xml, and the structure of the xml.  Without seeing the xml I can't tell.  Usually with SOAP you usually need to parse the entire xml and most people use XmlSerialization since the SOAP usually has a schema and you can use the xsd tool to create the c# classes that is needed for XmlSerialization.